# i am having trouble getting checkbox.checked working

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I can not seem to get checkbox.checked to work,  I have a script that changes an image based onclick() however i would like it to change it based on whether a checkbox is checked or not. what am i doing wrong? Also if someone may be able to adress this, the check boxes do not check in ie8

here is the live link: http://jsbin.com/uburan/1/edit

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function func()
{
    var img1= document.getElementById("img1");

    if(checkbox.checked)
    {
        img1.src = "images/" + "img1a.jpg";
        img1.name = "off";
    }
    else
    {
        img1.src = "images/" + "img1.jpg";
        img1.name = "on";
    }
}
</script>



</head>

<body>
<form>
<p align="center">
<input type="checkbox" name="interest1" id="interest1" value="x">
<input type="checkbox" name="interest2" id="interest2" value="x">
<input type="checkbox" name="interest3" id="interest3" value="x"></p>   
<p align="center">
<label for="interest1" id="label-interest1"><img src="images/img1.jpg" width="781" height="800" onclick="func()" id="img1" /></label>
<label for="interest2" id="label-interest2"><img src="/images/img2.jpg" width="781" height="800" /></label>
<label for="interest3" id="label-interest3"><img src="/images/img3.jpg" width="781" height="800" /></label></P><!-- code making checkbox be an image-->
</form>
```

Comment: "checkbox" isn't some magical variable that's automatically hooked up to your form. You need to define it from the DOM.

Comment: var checkbox = document.getElementById("interest1")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the ID of the checkbox (or its reference inside the DOM). Something like this:

```
if(document.getElementById('interest1').checked)
{
    // blah
}
```

If you want to check if they're all checked:

```
if(document.getElementById('interest1').checked && 
   document.getElementById('interest2').checked &&
   document.getElementById('interest3').checked) {

    // blah

}
```

Comment: Thank man! I realize my question may seem obvious, unfortunately Javsscript is not my best language, any chance you can take a gander at why this wont work on ie8?

Comment: Do you have a live link I can I look over?

Comment: Did you even read the answer? It looks like you've made no attempt to implement my answer... Without knowing how you want to the logic to perform, it's going to be impossible to help.

Comment: No, the checkbox does work, the javascript is working perfect thank you very much, however my form is not working in ie7 and 8 i was wondering if you may be able to explain to me why

Comment: When you say the 'form is not working in ie7 and 8', how do you mean?

Comment: When you check one of the images, the checkboxes do not get checked, nothing happens. i assumed it was due to the fact that an image tag is nested inside of a label tag, im just not sure how to resolve this.